# Get textbox value inside templateField tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get textbox value inside `templateField` tag?

Here's my code:

```
 <Fields>
   <asp:TemplateField >
     <ItemTemplate >
     <asp:TextBox ID="SUBJEK" runat="server" Width="600px" Text='<%# Bind("SUBJEK") %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Fields>
```

And i try to get value with:

```
TextBox subjek = (TextBox)DV1.FindControl("SUBJEK") as TextBox;
```

But, it didnt work. This the error message:

> "Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'JobList.TextBox'"

Comment: DV1 is the ID of detailsView control...
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another class in your namespace called `TextBox`.

Check, `JobList.TextBox` is not the asp.net TextBox.

This should help:

```
var subjek = (TextBox)DV1.FindControl("SUBJEK") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Textbox;
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that bit. When two classes have the same name, you use namespaces to differentiate.

Comment: hey,,,it works!Thanks @nunespascal...
here's my final code :
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox subjekT = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DV1.FindControl("SUBJEK") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox;

but i dont know why its work?could u please tell me?

Comment: If two classes have the same name, .net does not know which class to use with only the class name. This can happen very often when you are using others dlls, that is why we have namespaces.You really should readup about namespaces, assemblies, and full qualified names. Google should get you started.

Comment: This should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: oke...thank buddy..
but could you point out where's my mistakes?

Comment: You had two classes with the same name, and didn't qualify your class with a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You have go to the cell for finding control, Provide the row index and column index

```
int indexOfRowYouAreFinding = 0;
int indexOfColYouAreFinding = 2;

TextBox subjek = DV1.Rows[indexOfRowYouAreFinding].Cells[indexOfColYouAreFinding].FindControl("SUBJEK")[0] as TextBox;
```

Comment: it still didnt work.. heres the error message "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.Control'...

Comment: Won't work, you have your own class called `TextBox`. See if my reply helps.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` method returns an `array` of controls not a single control, so you need to mention the `index`.

```
TextBox subjek = DV1.FindControl("SUBJEK")[0] as TextBox;
```

Comment: it still didnt work..
heres the error message "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.UI.Control'"
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple rows in the details view, so you have to give the index of the row from which you select the textbox value.
`TextBox t= ( TextBox )DV1.Rows[0].FindControl("SUBJEK");`

This code will return the first row value.

Comment: didnt work..
""Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'JobList.TextBox'"

i think the problem is a casting method to TextBox...is that the only one way to casting the TextBox?

Comment: can u please post your complete code with the details view so we can understand better